# How to pass message headers through pseudo transaction manager?

Tags: spring-integration

I am polling for files for a service-activator, using a PseudoTransactionManager to move them into processed/failed directories. 
If/when the move fails, I would like to log this, including the file name.

As the information being passed around the flows is the Message object, I tried enriching the file name onto its header, but as we make copies of it for each step, this won't work unless I can move the header-enricher between the inbound channel adapter and transaction manager.

In simplified form the main flow I now have is this:

- inbound-channel-adapter -> a) header-enricher -> service-activator

Because I want the files moved to a processed or failed directory, there is a second flow:

- inbound-channel-adapter -> b) pseudo transaction-manager -> logging-channel-adapter (in case of problems moving the processed file).

I think this follows because the transaction manager definition is nested within the channel adapter definition in the xml.

How can I pass this information through the example setup here to a logging channel adapter?

Answer (score 0):

The transaction stuff only has access to the original message. You can add an `error-channel` to the poller; the default error channel (`errorChannel`) is a pub/sub channel and has a logging channel adapter subscribed to it.

When an exception occurs, an `ErrorMessage` is sent to the error channel (if configured); the payload is a `MessagingException` with `cause` and `failedMessage` properties. The `failedMessage` is the message at the point the failure occurred.

The default error flow will simply log the message so your "transaction" will "commit".

Instead, you need a custom error flow; log what you want and then re-throw the cause and your "transaction" will "rollback".